# d3.event.active purpose in drag-dropping circles

Tags: d3.js

I'm roughly familiar with how dragging works in d3. But I found something that flummoxed me recently.

Following through the code to create a f[orce directed graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) I can't follow the code to deal with dragging the nodes around:

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

Any idea why we're checking the if statement here in dragstarted and dragended?

I tried removing the if-condition and didn't really see much of a difference with the force directed graph. That is, instead of

```
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
```

I put

```
simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
```

and didn't see much of a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `active` property is described [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag-events). It indicates how many drag events, other than the one the event is currently being fired for, are currently ongoing, and is only really relevant for multitouch scenarios. The reason this check is used is to keep the simulation going as long as there is at least one active drag occurring.

For example, if there are no active drags occurring, and you start dragging, in `dragstarted` `d3.event.active` will be 0, and the force simulation will start up. If `d3.event.active !== 0`, then there is already a drag occurring and the simulation is already ongoing.

Likewise, in `dragended`, if `d3.event.active !== 0`, then another drag is still occurring and we don't want to stop the simulation. If `d3.event.active === 0`, then this was the last drag and we want to stop the simulation.

Comment: Ah. I think I understand. Would a multitouch drag fire if I'm looking at a force simulation on an iPad, and I dragged two circles with two different fingers at the same time? Any idea if its possible to have a multitouch drag when you're looking at the force simulation not using a touchscreen?

Comment: `dragstarted` would be called once for each of the two fingers. The first time it get's called `d3.event.active` would be 0, and the simulation would be restarted. The second time `d3.event.active` would be 1, so the simulation wouldn't restart again, because it's already going. `dragged` and `dragended` would also be called for each finger.

As for not using a touchscreen, I'm sure there are ways to have multiple clicks and drags. But with a typical mouse setup there wouldn't really be a way to have multiple drags occurring.

Answer (score 6):

(This answers OP's first question, not the new one regarding the `if` condition)

> I tried removing it and didn't really see much of a difference with the force directed graph.

Didn't you? The difference is quite big and very noticeable.

Without this line in the `dragstarted`:

```
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
```

The simulation is not restarted when you drag a node. I made a bl.ocks copying Bostock's code and deleting that line only. Wait until the force **stops** (around 5 seconds) and try to drag a node:

https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/7ad316f78d18233c1408d27c8ff58e0e

Did you see? You can't!

And, for this line in the `dragended`:

```
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
```

Without it, the simulation never stops, it keeps slowly moving forever after you stop dragging the node. I made another bl.ocks copying Bostock's code and deleting that line only, try it:

https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/6efa5edf188b3c87b7adbc877672b725

Comment: Sorry, I worded my question badly. 
I meant if Ichange 
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
to 
simulation.alphaTarget(0);
then I see no difference. Else you're right, it's a big difference! Changed question to clarify

Comment: @puzzler10 No worries, but you've made a *different* question here.

Comment: so...why do we check  "if (!d3.event.active)"?

Comment: @puzzler10 I see that this question still has no answer, even after 1 week. What's probably happening is that people see my answer and move on, they don't see that you edited your question. That being the case, I suggest you post *another* question, specifying the doubt regarding the `if` conditional.